# Solve first order non-linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've got such equation: $$5x^3(y')^2+5x^2yy'-3=0$$ I've tried to solve the quadratic eqaution w.r.t $y'$ but it lead me to non-linear equation which is not usefull as I could see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the derivative of the equation and test if the coefficient of $y''$ can be divided out, modulo the original equation. If the equation can be transformed into a Clairaut equation, then this should work.
\begin{align}
x(y')^2+yy'&=\frac3{5x^2}\\
(2xy'+y)y''+2(y')^2&=-\frac6{5x^3}=-2\left((y'^2)+\frac{yy'}x\right)\\
(2xy'+y)(xy''+2y')&=0
\end{align}
So on segments where the first factor is zero one has $y'=\frac{y}{2x}$, inserted into the original equation that gives
$$
\frac3{5x^2}=\frac12yy'=\frac{y^2}{4x}\implies y=\pm2\sqrt{\frac3{5x}}.
$$
On segments where the second factor is zero, $x^2y'=C$ can be inserted,
$$
y=\frac{3}{5x^2y'}-xy'=\frac{3}{5C}-\frac{C}{x}
$$

Comment: Yes, It's good solution. I hadn't heard about Clairaut equation.

Answer (score 3):

$$5x^3(y')^2+5x^2yy'-3=0$$
$$xy' + y - \dfrac{3}{5x^2y'} = 0$$
Change the variable $u=1/x$
$$y'=\dfrac {dy}{d1/x}\dfrac{d1/x}{dx}=-x^{-2}\dfrac {dy}{d1/x}$$
$$y'=-u^2\dfrac {dy}{du}$$
The ODE becomes:
$$y=uy' - \dfrac{3}{5y'} $$
$$y=uy'+f(y')$$
This is [Clairaut's differential equation .](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_equation)